# Tableau: Marking Cities and Towns on a Map

Tags: maps, visualization, tableau-api

I have made a map with Tableau that shades based on the number of customers we have by county. I am trying to add labels of towns/cities in the area.

I tried going to map options --> Place names but there are two problems with this. First the places appear under the shading, secondly many places (some of the towns aren't big enough to be included on a standard list) are not included on the map.

I tried overlaying a custom list of city locations on top of the counties; but it seems to only load one or the other.

Comment: Try it, then post a question if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- Go to `Map Layers > Washout` - modify it to see whether it improves the effect
- Go to `Marks > Color > Transparency` and modify it.
- Load a custom list with city names and their location.
- Use the `county` variable as `Label`.

One of these should work.

Also, Tableau's place names are not complete so there will be gaps for smaller cities/towns. However, they will appear when you zoom in.

Tableau 10 should have improved mapping options so maybe that will solve your problem.